# Is it possible to declare/implement a template within a function scope?

Tags: c++, templates

Title == Question.

To be very specific, is it possible to implement std::sinh like this?

```
namespace std {
    long double sinh(const long double arg) {
        template <long double _arg> long double _sinh() {
            // sinh implementaion here
        }
        template <> long double _sinh<0>() {return 0;}
        template <> long double _sinh<-0>() {return -0;}
        template <> long double _sinh<INFINITY>() {return INFINITY;}
        template <> long double _sinh<-INFINITY>() {return -INFINITY;}
        return _sinh<arg>();
    }
}
```

I know, this is a stupid idea, but I am really curious.

Comment: This is wrong in a couple of ways

Comment: I know, I made typo a few seconds ago.

Comment: `namestace` is the best one

Comment: People seem to think that c++ will sing their favourite song if you just type it with enough template braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare/implement a template within a function scope?

No. [temp]/p2:

> A *template-declaration* can appear only as a namespace scope or class scope declaration.

And lest you think this allows for template declarations inside local classes, [temp.mem]/p2:

> A local class of non-closure type shall not have member templates.

There are also various other problems with your code, two of which are noted in Mike Seymour's answer.

It is likely though that something like `sinh` can be implemented as a `constexpr` function, permitting evaluation at compile time if the argument is a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

There are two three problems:

- template paramaters can't have floating-point type
- template arguments must be constant expressions, which precludes a function argument.
- function definitions can only be at namespace scope. You could make it lambda, or a member of a local class, if you wanted to make it inaccessible for some reason.

Comment: It is POSSIBLE to have non-type parameters in template, but yes, I agree that const long double arg isn't a constant expression.

Comment: - declaring things in the `std` namespace can result in UB

Comment: @DannyuNDos: But it's not possible to have non-type parameters of floating-point type.

Comment: I'm not trying overloading it, I'm trying implementing the standard.

Comment: @Jefffrey: This is asking about implementing a standard library function. It's fine to declare things in `std` if you're writing the standard library (although you should also make sure you use reserved names for any identifiers that aren't part of the library specification).

Comment: @DannyuNDos: Because the standard says so. I don't know the exact rationale behind the restriction.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ah, I see it now.